# Grabbing API via JSON and displaying

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm having trouble displaying data that I am getting through API via JSON. My code is as follows

```
var nextSessionAPI = 'www.someapi.co.uk';
getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey);
function getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey) {
    jQuery.getJSON(nextSessionAPI, function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.Data.Session, function(index, sessions) {
            console.log('success');
            if(jQuery.trim(sessions.StartDate).exists()) {
                 console.log(sessions.StartDate);
            };  
        });
    });
}
```

Checking the console I am getting the API back so I think my code is okay upto console.log('success');.

The API is as follows:

```
{
    "Parameters":{
        "EditionId":45,
    },
    "Data": 
    [
        {
            "__type":"Session:ID",
            "Id":
                {
                    "Id":1251,
                },
            "DisplayName":"Some event",
            "EndDate":"\/Date(1366712700000)\/",
            "StartDate":"\/Date(1366711200000)\/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. p.s. go easy on me, my JS and JSON isn't the strongest!

Comment: That API response is not JSON it is XML ?

Comment: There is actually something in the backend that is translating it into JSON, I can put the output up if you like?

Comment: it would make it easier to identify a problem.

Comment: Have made that change olly_uk.

Comment: There's no `Section` inside `Data`.

Comment: Since when `String` got a method named `exists`?

Comment: Thank you for the help olly_uk and Shikiryu.

Answer (score 0):

The json doesn't contain any property named Sessions for Data so you have to change your script to `jQuery.each(data.Data, function(...))`.

```
var nextSessionAPI = 'www.someapi.co.uk';
getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey);
function getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey) {
    jQuery.getJSON(nextSessionAPI, function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.Data, function(index, sessions) {
             /* do funky stuff here */
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Since when `String` got a method named `exists`?

Answer (score 0):

your fix:

```
var nextSessionAPI = 'www.someapi.co.uk';
getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey);
function getSessionValues(exhibitionID,sessionKey) {
    jQuery.getJSON(nextSessionAPI, function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.Data, function(index, sessions) {
            console.log('success');
            if(jQuery.trim(sessions.StartDate).exists()) {
                 console.log(sessions.StartDate);
            };  
        });
    });
}
```

data.Data is a list of sessions. Data does not conaint a key: `Session`

Comment: Thank you! I was being a bit blonde there.

Comment: Since when `String` got a method named `exists`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that .exists has something set to it in another global js file. But thank you for your solution, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.trim` returns a string, on which you can't call `exists` which might be why you are getting an error. I get the error "TypeError: Object aaa has no method 'exists'" if I call exists on a string. Since the StartDate is "/Date(1366711200000)/" in your JSON, it will either be a valid date or null so...

Try replacing the line:

```
if(jQuery.trim(sessions.StartDate).exists())
```

With just simple:

```
if(sessions.StartDate)
```

Comment: Cheers. Though I forgot to say I did have a command for ".exists" in a sep global JS file.